# React Native TypeSrcript Function Returning JSX.Element Type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jsx, eslint

I've got a TypeScript function which returns a React Native `View`.

```
import React from "react";
import JSX, {View} from "react-native";

class DummyClass {
    static getView() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}/>
        );
    }
}

export default DummyClass;
```

And I'm calling this function in this way:

```
import JSX from "react-native";
import DummyClass from "./util/dummy";

const DummyWrapper = () => {
    return (DummyClass.getView());
};

export default DummyWrapper;
```

And when I run `eslint`, I get a warning.

> 5:5  warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types

So, I need to be returning something. `JSX.Element` seems reasonable enough, but that doesn't seem to be working. For one, when I try to return a `JSX.Element`, VSCode can't resolve it and pretends it's `any` instead. And moreover, it causes errors in other places that call the function.

So, doing this:
`static getView() : JSX.Element {`
and `const DummyWrapper = () : JSX.Element => {`

Results in the following error in `DummyCaller`:

> 5:5  error  Unsafe return of an any typed value  @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return

So now I'm not sure exactly what to do. I've tried a few other things, such as returning `View`, `typeof View`, `React.Component` (and `typeof`), and a few other things. I've also messed around with where JSX is being imported from. If I import from `react`, it seems to work even worse than if I import it from `react-native`. Also in my research, I see the most common problem is that one's React and React Native types are out of date, but as far as I can tell, I'm on the most up-to-date versions.

My `packages.json`:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "lint": "eslint -c .eslintrc.js --ext .tsx ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@dudigital/react-native-zoomable-view": "^1.0.15",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.3",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.6",
    "change-case": "^4.1.1",
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.8",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.13.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.53",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.63.27",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.9",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.9.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.5.0",
    "commonjs": "latest",
    "eslint": "^7.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^30.7.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "^1.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.13",
    "requirejs": "latest",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

React should be putting `JSX` into the global namespace, so if you don't import it from anywhere then returning `JSX.Element` should work.

You can also `import {ReactElement} from "react"` and return `ReactElement`.

You can also `import {FunctionComponent} from "react"` and type the `DummyWrapper` function itself, not the return type, as `DummyWrapper: FunctionComponent<{}>`.

There's a lot of options.

But I really do not understand the use case where you would be creating an element from a `static` method on a class.  This seems like a bad design that you should rethink.  Can you make `getView` into a function component?  Do you need the class `DummyClass` at all?

Comment: You're probably right that it's a bad design, thanks for saying that. I haven't seen the pattern before so in the back of my mind I thought it could be an antipattern (I'm good at inventing those).

This is a simplification of my real use case; in reality, the "`DummyClass`" has multiple functions that return different types of `View`s (such as also `ScrollView`s). The point of having them all in one class was to standardize the styles between my `View`/`ScrollView` components. I can probably break the class and turn it into multiple functional components instead. Thank you!